# JPA Criteria check input dates range present or not

Tags: jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CC_PLANNING_CYCLE")
public class PlanningCycleEntity implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long forcastCycleId;

    @Column(name = "FORECAST_CYCLE_NAME")
    private String planningCycleName;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "TIME_WINDOW_START_DATE")
    private Date timeWindowStartDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "TIME_WINDOW_END_DATE")
    private Date timeWindowEndDate;
}
```

Table:

```
|Plan Id   |  Name    |TimewindowStartDate  | timeWindowEnddate|
|1         |  Plan1   | 01-Jan-2021         | 15-Jan-2021      |
|2         |  Plan2   | 18-Jan-2021         | 02-Feb-2021      |
|3         |  Plan3   | 20-Feb-2021         | 25-Feb-2021      |
```

Desired output:

```
Input date 1 : 01-Jan-2021 and 17-Jan-2021   --- present
Input date 2 : 10-Feb-2021 and 27-Feb-2021  ---- present
Input Date 3 : 04-Feb-2021 and 10-Feb-2021  ---  not present.
```

Please help me how to write a JPA criteria query for above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use custom validator in which you can define the min and max date based on the parameter's  like **@DateRange(firstDate = "01/01/1900", lastDate="31/12/2025")**

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "TIME_WINDOW_START_DATE")
@DateRange(firstDate = "01/01/1900", lastDate="31/12/2025")
private Date timeWindowStartDate;
```

Comment: I think OP is asking not about validation, but about searching

Comment: Nikolai, you are right , I need search based on input.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have achieved through criteria, getting excepted result.

```
Predicate startDateInBetween = criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("timeWindowStartDate"), startDate),criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("timeWindowEndDate"), startDate));
            Predicate endDateInBetween = criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("timeWindowStartDate"), endDate),criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("timeWindowEndDate"), endDate));
            
            Predicate startGreaterThan = criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("timeWindowStartDate"), startDate),criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("timeWindowStartDate"), endDate));
            Predicate endLessThan = criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("timeWindowEndDate"), startDate),criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("timeWindowEndDate"), endDate));
            
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.or(startDateInBetween, endDateInBetween,startGreaterThan,endLessThan));
```